# std::condition_variable usage inside QThread::run()

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, qthread

I'm currently facing a problem in using `std::condition_variable`inside `QThread`.
When I call `nofity_one`or `notify_all`inside the `QThread::run()` method my thread crashes ("QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running").

```
class ThreadImpl : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    ThreadImpl(QObject* parent = 0);

    std::shared_ptr<std::mutex> GetMutexEventIsInit();

    std::condition_variable m_isInit;

protected:
    void run();

private:
    mutable std::shared_ptr<std::mutex> m_pMutexEventIsInit;
    mutable QMutex m_mutexPtrConnection;

};


void AWSIoTConnectionUserRunner::run()
{
    cout << DBGFUNC_CPP << endl;
    {
        // do init work here

        // inform all 'waiters' that connection is initialized
        m_isInit.notify_one();
    }

    exec();     // <-- crashes here inside event-loop

    cout << DBGFUNC_CPP << "- quits." << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    ThreadImpl impl;
    impl.start();

    // wait for connection to init
    shared_ptr<mutex> pMutexUserConnectionInit = impl.GetMutexEventIsInit();
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(*pMutexUserConnectionInit);
        runnerUserConnection.m_isInit.wait(lock);
    }
    cout << "This text never appears, because my program crashes before with:" << endl;
    cout << "QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running"
}
```

I know that there is `QWaitCondition`for this matter but I just don't get why it does not work with the one of the STL. Additionally I also assume that the crash is caused because an element is accessed which was not created by the thread but as far as I know `std::condition_variable`should be thread-safe.

Do you know what is wrong in my code?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I am not sure but maybe the way how are managed thread in Qt have nothing to do with std thread. That's why condition variable does not work.

By the way, your thread management is wrong. QThread is not mean to be inherited from

http://blog.qt.io/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/

Comment: I suspect your program does reach `cout << ...` statements, but because it crashes shortly thereafter, the output doesn't have a chance to get from runtime buffers onto the actual console. You allow `main` to terminate, and destroy local `impl` variable, while the thread is still running.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks for your answer. I just realized that I made a huge mistake. I commented out the ´QCoreApplication::exec()´ call at the end of my ´main´ function. So your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment of @IgorTandetnik helped me.
I just forgot to call `QCoreApplication::exec()`at the end of my main function.

This led to the behaviour that my thread is killed because my main-function goes out of scope before it is able to do it's work which causes the Qt-event-loop accessing objects which are already deleted.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    ThreadImpl1impl;
    impl.start();

    // wait for connection to init
    shared_ptr<mutex> pMutexUserConnectionInit = impl.GetMutexEventIsInit();
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(*pMutexUserConnectionInit);
        runnerUserConnection.m_isInit.wait(lock);
    }
    cout << "This text never appears, because my program crashes before with:" << endl;
    cout << "QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running"

    // This is what I forgot:
    return a.exec();
}
```